# How to give the long name as a field of the table?

Tags: mysql

How can I give the long text as a table field name in mysql?

Here is what I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS surveyForm_8(
    surveyForm_8_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(surveyForm_8_id), 
    survey_form_id VARCHAR(255), 
    submitted_by VARCHAR(15), 
    submitted_on TIMESTAMP, 
    'How_to_change_the_way_of_road?' VARCHAR(255)
)
```

But I got this error:

```
#1059 error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: You need to quote it with backticks `\`How_to_change_the_way_of_road?\`` though I would recommend against including the `?` in the table name.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it is not coming...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I definitely agree what you've said but is not error `#1059` thrown because of length of the column name?

Comment: The backticks worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: Check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html. You can  specify column name maximum 64 characters long

Comment: @SaharshShah i need more than 64 convectors is possible? or suggest me any other way?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, you should use the ` symbol for column names

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS surveyForm_8(surveyForm_8_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY(surveyForm_8_id), survey_form_id varchar(255) ,submitted_by varchar(15),
     submitted_on timestamp, `How_to_change_the_way_of_road?` varchar(255));
```

Comment: it is ok ?But if the size of the field name exceeds 64 characters means What can i do?....

Comment: @siva-g Nothing, just use less than 64 characters, it's rule :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html for valid table and field names.

Basically, double quotes only work in [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) mode. The default is to use `backticks` to quote. Also, the maximum length of table / field names is 64 characters.